# usuario o contraseña invalido en todo momento

Tags: php, mysql

hola estoy haciendo mi login pero siempre me aparece que el usuario y la contraseña son invalidos. ya he revisado muchas veces y nada que encuentro el error

```
<?php include("conexion.php");
   session_start();if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // usuario y contraseñas enviados desde el formulario

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['correo']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['contrasenia']);

      $sql = "SELECT idUsuario FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$myusername' and contraseña = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['idUsuario'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // Si el resultado coincide con $ myusername y $ mypassword, la fila de la tabla debe ser 1 fila

      if($count == 1) {
         //session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: ../index.php");
      }else {
         $error = "tu usuario o contraseña son invalidas";
         header("location: login.php?fallo=true");}}?>

<?php
if(isset($_GET["fallo"]) && $_GET["fallo"] == 'true'){ echo "<center><div style='color:red'>Usuario o contraseña invalido</div></center>";}?>
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" method="post" action=""><div id="contenedor">
<div id="inputs">
                <label id="ingresar">Ingrese su Usuario:</label>
                <input name ="correo" type="text" id="correo" placeholder="Correo Institucional" >

               <label id="ingresar">Ingrese su Contraseña:</label>
               <input  name="contrasenia" type="password" id="contrasenia" placeholder="Contraseña" >
                  </div>

                  <div id="btn">
                   <input type="submit" name="submiti" id="submiti" value="Iniciar Sesión" >
                  </div>
             <div id="pie">
                 <a id="pie" href="#">Si olvidó su usuario o contraseña por favor comuniquese con el administrador </a>
                </div>
         </div>
</form>
```

Comment: faltan cosas a tu código, como comienza el "form"?,cual es tu controlador? agrega lo comentado

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte, debes incluir tu código de PHP donde realizas la consulta a la base de datos.

Comment: la plataforma no lo mostraba, y el "form" si lo tengo solo que el html se esta ejecutando en este sitio web

Comment: Si haces un echo de $count que valor tenes?

Comment: no lo muestra, si lo hago mostrar en el html me dice que la variable es indefinida, y si lo muestro en el php no muestra nada

Comment: Se te oucrrio pensar entonces que el error viene de antes de eso?? ;) si no hay count, obviamente no va a ser nunca == 1

Comment: Y nunca pero nunca las claves en una base de datos se guardan planas, es decir sin encriptar.

Answer (score 0):

Debes especificar el `action="nombretupagina.algo"` en el formulario.
Y esta linea del query, puedes modificarla.

```
$sql = "SELECT idUsuario FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '".$myusername."' and contraseña = '".$mypassword."'  ";
```